# Retrieving value from single-line Perl script

Tags: perl, shell, windows-shell

I am attempting to parse an output file for some data, and am having problems returning the value to my Windows shell.

What I am trying to do is simply return a value using a simple regular expression, and store that into my shell variable.

I currently have something like this:

```
%VAL% = %PERL% -e '$tmp="Value: 1000"; if ($tmp =~ /Value:\s(\d+)/) { print $1; }'
```

where `%VAL%` is where I'd like to return what was found in `$1`, and `%PERL%` points to a local copy of perl.exe.

Can somebody please point out the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: It's a bit uglier than Unix:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('perl -e "$tmp=\"Value: 1000\"; if ($tmp =~ /Value:\s(\d+)/) { print $1; }"') do set VAL = %i
```

Or use `set /p` with an intermediary file:

```
%PERL% -e '$tmp="Value: 1000"; if ($tmp =~ /Value:\s(\d+)/) { print $1; }' > file.txt
set /p VAL = < file.txt
del file.txt
```

From [Silly Batch File Tricks](http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2006/03/24/silly-batch-file-tricks-redirecting-stdout-into-an-evironment-variable-and-dp0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the variable inside the script? see [env_var](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Environment_Variables) on win32 perl wiki.

Comment: If the variable is set with env_var, it will be visible only in programs started from within the script -- but it will not be exported outside the script when the script ends

Comment: Don't know (and can't test) but I thought an "export" like would do it. my mistake!